# How to solve NOTES keeps showing the execution security warning window?

Tags: ecl, ibm-domino, hcl-notes

1.No action

2.Perform this action this time

3.Trust the signer to perform this action of this Notes session

4.Start trusting the signer to perform this action

Some users will appear in the "Enforce Security Alert" window when using NOTES. At present, users are asked to select item 4 by themselves, but this problem often occurs.

Is there a way to solve this problem at once without letting the user personally operating?

Sorry, only the Chinese version of the screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Security Settings policy document to the Domino Directory that contains entries for a standard Execution Control List. The Domino Admin help database explains this in more detail.